# Strange 404 errors with bits of jQuery library code

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-404

I've got a script that emails me when I get 404 errors on my site. In the past few months, I've seen lots of errors coming back that have various bits of the jQuery library in the URL. I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this sort of thing and what they did to fix it.

The 404 errors appear to come from a wide variety of browsers and platforms. (Windows + IE 8, Mac + Safari, etc.)

Examples:

```
Accessing: http://ddmgaragedoors.com/springs/},cur:function(a){if(this.elem[this.prop]!=null&&(!this.elem.style||this.elem.style[this.prop]==null))return%20this.elem[this.prop];return(a=parseFloat(c.css(this.elem,this.prop,a)))&&a>-10000?a:parseFloat(c.curCSS(this.elem,this.prop))||0},custom:function(a,b,d){function%20f(j){return%20e.step(j)}this.startTime=J();this.start=a;this.end=b;this.unit=d||this.unit||
Referer: http://ddmgaragedoors.com/springs/garage-door-springs.php

Accessing: http://ddmgaragedoors.com/springs/).css(
Referer: http://ddmgaragedoors.com/springs/garage-door-springs.

Accessing: http://ddmgaragedoors.com/diy-instructions/);this.elem.style.display=a?a:this.options.display;if(c.css(this.elem,
Referer: http://ddmgaragedoors.com/diy-instructions/troubleshooting.php
```

Comment: how are you capturing client requests?? i don't think jquery will have anything do that , might be the server which has jquery was unable to get resolved from outside or so??

Answer (score 0):

first validate your pages
http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://ddmgaragedoors.com/diy-instructions/troubleshooting.php

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Didn't realize I had so many issues - I built the layout a while back and then others have added content, etc. I've cleaned up several pages but I'm still getting the 404 errors. Here's the latest: Accessing: http://ddmgaragedoors.com/],rb=s.defaultView&&s.defaultView.getComputedStyle,Pa=c.support.cssFloat?
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C)

Comment: your linking to them here invites googlebot and all to come on and hit them

Comment: I would suggest checking the pages via a spider like http://validator.w3.org/checklink